# Compute GPA for a set of grades

Tags: code-golf

Given a set of letter grades, output the GPA (grade point average) of those grades, rounded to one decimal place.

Valid grades and their corresponding value are the following:

```
A = 4 grade points
A- = 3.7 grade points
B+ = 3.3 grade points
B = 3 grade points
B- = 2.7 grade points
C+ = 2.3 grade points
C = 2 grade points
C- = 1.7 grade points
D+ = 1.3 grade points
D = 1 grade point
D- = 0.7 grade points
F = 0 grade points
```

The formula for GPA is simply the average of the points values of the grades.   The rounding scheme used should be [round half up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_up) (i.e. less than 0.05 gets rounded down to 0 and greater than or equal to 0.05 gets rounded up to 0.1).  The average should be unweighted (all inputs are treated equally).  Note that the same grade can show up multiple times in the input, in which case each instance of that grade should be a separate element in the average.

So for example, if the input was [A, B+, A, C-], the GPA is (4 + 3.3 + 4 + 1.7)/4 = 3.25, which rounds to 3.3.

The program should take as input the grades to be averaged using whatever format is convenient, such as a list, or a string with a delimiter of your choice.  Each input grade should be a single string (i.e. the letter components and +/- shouldn't be separate inputs).  You can assume the input will always contain at least one grade.  Note that grades may be repeated in the input.

Output can optionally include the ".0" suffix in the event of an integer result but this is not required.

This is code golf, so shortest solution in bytes wins.

Test cases:

```
[A] => 4
[F, F, F] => 0
[D+, D-] => 1
[A, B, C, D] => 2.5
[A-, B-, C-, D-] => 2.2
[A, A-, B+, B, B-] => 3.3
[A, B+, A, C-] => 3.3
[C+, C+, A, C+] => 2.7
[A, B, F, F] => 1.8
```

Comment: So this is just replacing the grades with their corresponding values, and averaging?

Comment: "Input can be of whatever format is convenient" — Can we take the letters as one argument and the signs as another?

Comment: can we take the letters in lowercase

Comment: Are we allowed to output `4.0` instead of `4`?

Comment: @MatthewJensen Not OP but traditionally GPA is always written as 4.0, not 4 on report cards and such

Comment: @Adám each grade should be a string in the input.  I've edited to reflect this

Comment: @MatthewJensen having the trailing ".0" is fine

Comment: @thejonymyster input letters will always be capitalized

Comment: @Adám "So this is just replacing the grades with their corresponding values, and averaging" <= That is how I would program it, but there may be other ways to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ON%7’»0_2¦€4ḋ10,3Æm+.Ḟ÷⁵
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters and yields a number.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/fT9X8UcPMQ7sN4o0OLXvUtMbk4Y5uQwMd48Ntudp6D3fMO7z9UePW/4fbgVL//0dHqzuqx3LpRKu7qesowAiwgIs2iOOiC@E5gjhOIMIZLAwV1QULg0lnXQz1UGltuF4nFNPA4o5QvWBxZ7CQM5KENrr1cCfGAgA)**

#### How?

```
ON%7’»0_2¦€4ḋ10,3Æm+.Ḟ÷⁵ - Link: list of grades  e.g. ['A-', 'B+', 'F', 'F']
O                        - ordinals (vectorises)      [[65, 45], [66, 43], [70], [70]]
 N                       - negate                     [[-65, -45], [-66, -43], [-70], [-70]]
  %7                     - mod seven                  [[5, 4], [4, 6], [0], [0]]
    ’                    - decrement                  [[4, 3], [3, 5], [-1], [-1]]
     »0                  - max with zero              [[4, 3], [3, 5], [0], [0]]
        2¦€              - from 2nd of each:
       _   4             -   subtract four            [[4, -1], [3, 1], [0], [0]]
            ḋ10,3        - dot product with [10,3]    [37, 33, 0, 0]
                 Æm      - mean                       17.5
                   +.    - add a half                 18.0
                     Ḟ   - floor                      18
                      ÷⁵ - divide by ten              1.8
```

---

If banker's rounding was used \$21\$ bytes is possible with `ON%7’»0_2¦€4Uḅ.3Æmær1` (`U` reverses each, `ḅ.3` converts from base \$0.3\$, and `ær1` uses Python's `round` to round to 1 decimal place).

Answer (score 22):

## JavaScript (ES6), 67 bytes

Returns a number.

```javascript
a=>(a.map(([x,y])=>t+=940.5%(n++,'0x5'+x)%85+~~(y+3),n=t=0)|t/n)/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDfCoIwFAbw@55CBGnj6JypZBcLSuklZBfD/lDYjJIwiF7dcmpJWrs4V@e37@McxFVckvP@lFsyW2/KLSsFmyNBjuKEUFyYN47ZPAc28yjxDSQBzDEt/DEU2Ah8eDzQDVxsSpYziu@5LbHt0DLJ5CVLNyTNdmiLYn2hc234YazZtuaNvsVKN7V28AFBeyKCajuy@lG1cEb9Vi@wrEao6EfWYkL8vrEUUjO0uomtmQznNBDema8/eG1c4v7oprYXTRbvdhsyoVoPOwga1Hab/rnB97Gbq5GgfAI)

#### How?

The purpose of the black-magic formula `940.5 % ('0x5' + x) % 85` is to turn a grade into its base value pre-multiplied by \$10\$ and with an offset of \$1/2\$ for the final rounding.

| x | N = '0x5' + x | As decimal | 940.5 mod N | mod 85 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0x5A | 90 | 40.5 | 40.5 |
| B | 0x5B | 91 | 30.5 | 30.5 |
| C | 0x5C | 92 | 20.5 | 20.5 |
| D | 0x5D | 93 | 10.5 | 10.5 |
| F | 0x5F | 95 | 85.5 | 0.5 |

We use the expression `~~(y + 3)` to add an additional offset of \$\pm 3\$ if the grade is followed by `+` or `-`. This evaluates to `~~NaN` (which is \$0\$) if there's no modifier.

Given the sum \$t\$ of all these values, the GPA is given by \$\lfloor t/n\rfloor/10\$, where \$n\$ is the number of grades.

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 76 bytes

Original answer, returning a string.

```javascript
a=>(eval(a.map(s=>s<'F'&&'14-0x'+s+[s[1]&&.3]).join`+`)/a.length).toFixed(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDRCoIwFAbg@55CvNCNtWNmURcZlOFLyKBh0wxz0SR6e6upJWnt4lydb//POfEbV/E1u5S0kAdRJX7F/TUSN54jDmd@Qcpfq5Ud2pZluzM6udtEkUhFLrMs8BiGk8yKPdljh0MuirQ8YihlmN3FAbm4imWhZC4glylKUGRuTGYMP4wNxzFmo28RmmOjHWxATHpiR17bO9qPqoU76rd6gu1rBJp@ZC2mMO8bqpGeAe0mtmY6nNNA8s58/sFq44H3o5ve3jRZrNttyAR6Pegg0qC22@LPDb6P3VwNltUD)

#### How?

If the grade is `"F"`, we turn it into `"false"`.

Otherwise:

- we add the prefix `"14-0x"`
- if this is a two-character grade, we add the suffix `"0.3"`

Examples:

- `"A"` is turned into `"14-0xA"` (\$14-10=4\$)
- `"B+"` is turned into `"14-0xB+0.3"` (\$14-11+0.3=3.3\$)
- `"C-"` is turned into `"14-0xC-0.3"` (\$14-12-0.3=1.7\$)

Comment: Given the strict output format, it might be worth checking that `4.0` output is allowed

Comment: @MatthewJensen output formats are generally lax on this site

Comment: Really unexpected and creative.

Comment: 76 for the second one: `a=>(eval(a.map(s=>s<'F'&&'140-10*0x'+s+[s[1]&&3]).join`+`)/a.length+.5|0)/10`

Comment: @tsh Nice. Saved 3 bytes from there.

Comment: 72: `a=>(a.map(s=>t+=139-10*parseInt(s,14)-~(s[1]+3)|0,t=0)|t/a.length+.5)/10`

Answer (score 8):

## Excel, <s>89</s>  84 bytes

<sup>Saved 5 bytes thanks to [JvdV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/561216)</sup>

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(IF(A:A=0,"",FIND(LEFT(A:A),"FDCBA")-1+IFERROR(--RIGHT(A:A)&.3,0))),1)
```

Input is in the first column. One grade per row. When you paste the formula, Excel will automatically add a leading zero so `.3` becomes `0.3`.

- `ROUND(~,1)` will round the final result to one decimal place.
- `AVERAGE(~)` will average the array we're about to calculate.
- `IF(A:A=0,"",~)` will ignore all the blank cells below the input. Without this, the above solution produces around 1 million zeroes so that throws off the average a bit.
- BASE VALUE: `FIND(LEFT(A:A),"FDCBA")-1` get the base GPA value of each letter from 0 - 4.
- ADJUSTMENT VALUE: `IFERROR(--RIGHT(A:A)&.3,0)`

  - `RIGHT(A:A)&.3` combines the right-most character (which may be a letter) with `.3`.
  - `--~` tries to coerce that value into a number which throws an error if the right-most character was a letter since something like `--A.3` is not a number.
  - `IFERROR(~,0)` corrects all those errors to `0` instead.
- When you add the base value and adjustment value (which may be negative), you get the GPA value for that letter grade.
- All those grades are calculated individually and then averaged and rounded to one decimal place.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Note that you can change `VALUE()` to a double unary too saving a few bytes. Nice sollution once again.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 38 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous prefix lambda taking a string argument of whatever format is convenient.

```
{1⍕(+/l,.3×-⌿'+-'∘.=⍵)÷≢l←0⌈5-⎕A⍳⍵∩⎕A}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=qzZ81DtVQ1s/R0fP@PB03Uc9@9W1ddUfdczQs33Uu1Xz8PZHnYtyHrVNMHjU02Gq@6hvquOj3s1AmUcdK0GcWgA&f=e9Q39VHbhDQF9WjHWHWuR3Cem44CCKGIuWjrKLjoogg56ig46Sg4A8VRhXWB4kDsrItNB1hWG6zTCdM4oIQjSCeKhDNQ1Bkqo43FBRC3AgA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`:

`⍵∩⎕A` intersection of argument and uppercase **A**lphabet

`⎕A⍳` indices of those letters in the uppercase Alphabet (A=1)

`5-` subtract those indices from 5

`0⌈` maximum of 0 and those numbers

`l←` assign to `l`

`≢` count those

`(`…`)÷` divide the following by that:

`'+-'∘.=⍵` comparison table of signs vs the argument characters

`-⌿` subtract the bottom row from the top row

`.3×` multiply those differences by 0.3

`l,` prepend `l`

`+/` sum

`1⍕` format as string with 1 decimal

Answer (score 5):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, <s>302</s> 299 bytes

```
:a
s/ //
s/[A-D]/&aaaaaaaaaa/g
y/ABCD/BCDF/
s/\+/aaa/
/-/{s/-//;s/a//;s/a//;s/a//}
s/Fa/aF/
ta
s/F/!F/
:b
s/F/a/
s/(a+)(a*!)\1$/X\2\1/
tb
s/!.*/\U&/
s/AA?/a/g
/(a+)!\1$/s/a/X/
s/[a!]//g
s/X{10}/Y/g
s/$/I.0/
:c
/X/y/012345678/123456789/
/Y/y/IJKLMNOPQ/JKLMNOPQ9/
s/X//
s/Y//
tc
y/IJKLMNOPQ/012345678/
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDJTsMwFEXF1l_hVFXV1nJvU6YOAuQkRJQyLpASNVmYMq3YJCyqql_CBoRgyf_A1_CeQxli5en63eP7LD--FNdXb9Oa3q_lz3evD-WN7n-uqaEVBSRAdWp0lKNhfz7cijlMEEagP2YkU-C-gMaioIJRAfu_LgmLLSzxJWfH8EgOL520HNK0qtW0ba-V-XUkWS_zCWXf67SRXTSYMWYPPN_BHoMcnrhrWi8HWQWShd9dInW6jnGnS3Nmgqg5un5vfWNza7uPlRjQrVNyxoeTo-OT07NzrMSAUxP3BCnVcib-Ur9J1Zu9H4x4XnYPubMrv5tPHxMjYklLREpGWhgZyFBGwmgZaBnqqsc7RU7gACUNOSJUMnRSuVOUUWV-AQ)

**Explanation:**

```
                  # store dividend as unary "a" and divisor as unary "F"
:a
s/ //                 # removes all spaces
s/[A-D]/&aaaaaaaaaa/g # for each of letters ABCD ten "a" are added
y/ABCD/BCDF/          # each of letters ABCD are substracted to BCDE
s/\+/aaa/             # for every + three "a" are added
/-/{s/-//;s/a//;s/a//;s/a//} # for every - three "a" are removed
s/Fa/aF/              # sort the string into format "aaaaaFFFFF"
ta
                  # now perform the division
s/F/!F/               # transforms string to format "aaaaa!FFFFF"
:b
s/F/a/                # transforms string to format "aaaaa!aaaaa"
s/(a+)(a*!)\1$/X\2\1/ # if there are more or equal "a" on left side than on the right append "X" to beggining
tb
                  # now do the rounding
s/!.*/\U&/            # transorm "a" after "!" to "A"
s/AA?/a/g             # now the amount of "A" is divided by 2
/(a+)!\1$/s/a/X/      # check if the reminder is more or equal to half of divisor and if so, then add one more "X"
s/[a!]//g             # remove leftover characters
                  # now the result is stored as unary "X"
                  # conversion from unary to decimal
s/X{10}/Y/g           # convert every ten "X" to "Y"
s/$/I.0/              # adds string for output "I.0"
:c
/X/y/012345678/123456789/ # for every "X" the "0" is increased
/Y/y/IJKLMNOPQ/JKLMNOPQ9/ # for every "Y" the "I" is increased
s/X//
s/Y//
tc
y/IJKLMNOPQ/012345678/ # now the "I" is transformed to digit
```

Comment: Nice.  Mind adding a commented version?  Or high-level explanation of approach...

Comment: @Jonah Added the commented version.

Comment: despite it's practical cmdline uses, sed truly is an esolang, and a fascinating one. there is no question that it is harder to program in than, say, brainfuck.

Comment: @Jonah Hehe, I actually started programming in sed, because I consider it as easier version of brainfuck.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 98 bytes

```python
lambda i:round(sum(x*i.count(y)for y,x in zip("FDCBA-+",[*range(5),-.3,.3]))/len(i.split())+.01,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY3dasIwFMfv9xTBqxNzEicy2ApetCm-RJVRp50Hahr6AXavshth6Dv5Np7UboME_r_k__F99X17qNz5p1iuL11b6NfbtsyP210uKKqrzu2g6Y5wmpL5YGqhl0VVix5Pgpz4Ig-TVWqTWKsJZtM6d597eJGozQLNYiPlrNw7INP4klqQUpnnOc7luASh6j0UPYJvMvI18UgBFC3J-S5kkEb_-dZk8eYpW6EIh1WqUKSaRYwiQWGZAmgmvlb__w5vanAlvwHGOLgYLWs7svrrG1Ye23c)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: The `+.01` fudge to get rounding up is creative, but it won't work on sufficiently large inputs (ones with 20 grades for example).  Using Python2 (which had different rounding semantics) could do this correctly and save a few bytes.  Alternatively, in Python3: `int(10*...+0.5)/10`

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3.8, <s>95</s> <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```
s=.01;i=0
for g,a,*_ in open(0):i+=1;s+='FDCBA'.find(g);exec(f's=s{a}.3')
exit(f'{s/i:.1f}')
```

Input (stdin)

```
A
B+
C
D
```

Very straightforward. Open `stdin` with `open(0)`, then read each line with `for g`. Python has an annoying property where it leaves a trailing `\r` after each line, which we exploit in an f-string passed to `exec`. In case there's no appendix after grade, f-string becomes `s=s\r.3`, which is essentially a no-op. Very unsafe ;)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFLDoMgEADQ/ZyCuAGKoRI3DYaFn/QajWkZOxsg4kJjPDu@l47tH0P7Smsp2enGAMaVLfVcPz6MAovJB0HWNdKScqbzu/8KrLJy/D2NQ881UviJRZ7zpdtKgt9pE8jP/CSrDV5cltLDoGCECW4 "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>24</s> 29 bytes

```
.OmeS,0v++"14-0x"d?tld".3";.z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X88/NzVYx6BMW1vJ0ETXoEIpxb4kJ0VJz1jJWq/q/39HLkddLidtLicuJ10uZ20uZy5nXS4XbS4XLhddLjcA)

Comment: Running with `A\nB\nC\nD` as the input gives me output `4\n\n0\n\n0\n\n0`; should output 2.5

Comment: @Zags Well that's embarrassing, I somehow lost track of what the question was... fixed

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 93 bytes

```
lambda l:int(0.5+sum(3*(c=='+')-3*(c=='-')or'FDCBA'.index(c)*10for c in''.join(l))/len(l))/10
```

Takes input as a list of strings (`['A', 'B+']`).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <del>113</del> 96 bytes

-17 bytes thanks to celingcat and jdt

```c
k;i;main(j){for(;gets(&j);k++)i+=j%8<5?50-j%8*10:0,i+=(j>>=8)?132-j*3:0;printf("%.1f",i/10./k);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjdCoMgGADQex8jaGj2lS6CyFXsh72HSIo/uVHdjb36XHeHo0AFGU1KXlixSBuxIx/9WrEw877hkyPCU0osHVzeXdqpZXCg4Kxn5ZHYjePQkYk3Z3BF0zPxXm3cNc7yiuustDVnVe2J@KZ0BXQDdAf0APT8KR2k2RKE5Q8)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjcLs3UyrXMTM_M0sjSr0_KLNKzripMT89I0lFSLlXTUsjSts7W1NTO1bbNszA3sDc0tdA0NtLJUjUzNtDWy7Ows7A2NjXSNtcBsTSsDILIuKMrMKwEZoGeYpqSjkamdrW-kqZ-tb2igZ6BpXQuxGGr_gsUuXG4QJgA)

Takes input as one grade per line.

### Explanation

```c
gets(&j)
```

Read the string into a integer field `j`. This is perfectly valid in C, and is a compact way to read strings of upto 3 bytes long.

```c
j%8<5
```

Check for F

```c
50-j%8*10
```

Extract the last byte from the string, this will be the letter (since little endian). 178-10*char will be the letter grade, 40, 30, 20, 10 etc.

```c
0,
```

I think this just changed the operator precidence? Not sure.

```c
i+=(j>>=8)?132-j*3:0
```

Add or subtract 3 depending on the sign, since `+` is 43 and `-` is `45`

```c
printf("%.1f",i/10./k)
```

Round and print the final number as a float.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>30</s> 26 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε14sáC-.3y¦'\ìθ.VDd*}ÅA1.ò
```

-4 bytes by [semi-porting *@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251902/52210)

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZDk@LDC5119YwrDy1Tjzm85twOvTCXFK3aw62OhnqHN/3/H63kqKSj5KgLJJy0QQQIg3jOIJ4zCIN4LiCeCwiDeG5KsQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1sNTYoPL3TW1TOuPLRMPebwmnM79MJcUrRqD7c6Guod3vRf5390tJKjUqxOtJKbkg4Ug3gu2kCmiy6Y7QhkOgGxM0gIIqILEgIRzrqo6iAy2lAdTkgGgMQcITpAYs4gvjNcUBvFJqg7YgE).

**Original 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
•H₁yΔи•.¥RA4£…+ -â¦ðмuIkèÅAòT/
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcMij0dNjZXnplzYAWTrHVoa5GhyaPGjhmXaCrqHFx1adnjDhT2eOdmHVxxudTy8KUT///9oJUclHSVHXSDhpA0iQBjEcwbxnEEYxHMB8VxAGMRzU4oFAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/f9HDYs8HjU1Vp6bcmEHkK13aGmQo8mhxY8almkr6B5edGjZ4Q0X9lTmZB9ecbjV8fCmEP3/Ov@jo5UclWJ1opXclHSgGMRz0QYyXXTBbEcg0wmInUFCEBFdkBCIcNZFVQeR0YbqcEIyACTmCNEBEnMG8Z3hgtooNkHdEQsA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε            # Map over the (implicit) input-list:
 14          #  Push 14
   s         #  Swap so the current grade-string is at the top
    á        #  Only keep its letters (removing a potential "+"/"-")
     C       #  Convert it to 'binary': "A"=10, "B"=11, "C"=12, "D"=13, "F"=15
      -      #  Subtract it from the 14
 .3          #  Push 0.3
   y         #  Push the current grade-string again
    ¦        #  Remove its first character (the letter)
     '\ì    '#  Prepend a leading "\"
        θ    #  Pop and only keep its last character
         .V  #  Execute it as 05AB1E code
             #  ("+"/"-" does what you'd expect; "\" discards the 0.3 from the stack)
 D           #  Duplicate the decimal
  d          #  Check if it's non-negative (1 if >=0; 0 if <0)
   *         #  Multiply that to the decimal to change the "F"=1 to 0
}            # Close the map
 ÅA          # Get the average of this list
   1.ò       # Round it to 1 decimal point
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

```python
•H₁yΔи•      # Push compressed integer 73343343343
       .¥    # Undelta its digits with leading 0: [0,7,10,13,17,20,23,27,30,33,37,40]
         R   # Reverse it: [40,37,33,30,27,23,20,17,13,10,7,0]
A            # Push the lowercase alphabet
 4£          # Only keep its first four characters: "abcd"
   …+ -      # Push string "+ -"
       â     # Get the cartesian product of the two: ["a+","a ","a-",...,"d+","d ","d-"]
        ¦    # Remove the leading "a+"
         ðм  # Remove all spaces from each string
Il           # Push the input-list, and convert each grade-string to lowercase
  k          # Get the indices of each lowercase grade-string in the string-list we've created)
             # (-1 for "f", since it's not in the list)
  è          # Use that to index into the earlier list of integers
             # (-1 wraps around to the last item, which is the 0)
   ÅA        # Get the average of this list
     ò       # Round it to an integer
      T/     # Divide it by 10
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•H₁yΔи•` is `73343343343`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 124 bytes

```
func[a][forall a[parse a/1[change p: skip(rejoin[max 69 - p/1 0" "])opt[skip insert" .3"]]a/1: do a/1]round/to average a .1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BasMwDIbvfQrh00ZIszAYLNBBmrIH2FXoIGJnTZvaxnHH3j6Vm6aD1SCj/7P0ywpGT19GI626aurOtkUm7FzgYQBGz2E0wEWJ7Z7ttwFfwXjs/VMwB9dbPPEvvL1DDr4o4UWBomfnI6YS6O1oQlSwflVEYlGBdsmKgjtbXUQRPyawmDKsS5pkqOF2D9GMEXAFclDVim7Zp7jPsZBdJnKX33UtcivRJPxH84TT1eSP9fNrduvc/jNLvJ47F94k1twfsofpyx8JfeitbHJyg56XUpsPBd01J5ou)

More readable:

```
f: func [a][
    forall a [
        parse a/1 [
            change set g skip (rejoin [max 69 - g 0 space])
            opt [skip insert " 0.3"]
        ]
        a/1: do a/1
    ]
    round/to average a 0.1
]
```

The input is a block (list) of strings. I modify each string in place by changing the letter with the corresponding grade value and optionally appending "0.3" after `+` or `-`. Then the string is replaced by its evaluated value. Finally I find and round the average of the block.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 90 bytes

```
T`L`4-0
\d
0$&$*
1
20$*
\+
6$*
1{6}-

O`.
0+
$.&$*1$.&$*1,$.&$*
\D*(1+),(\1)*1*
$#2
.$
.$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUw9C8IwFNzvVwSMpc0XSZHuaYIugotjhgh2cHEQN/G3x5e0wr13d@8d91rej@et7PtTLtd8zgdtke6wvOMCDqMlShJTdZ/pq4FLNrAS3FDCrVs1Qoqid3JQfXKDcAJ8N8JwQleKx1GxCkSpWNTwis2KBdLwmjRN0P9Pu8iWmNcoGV8TCKTC5uTWUnt/) Link includes test cases. Output always includes the decimal but omits the leading `0` on scores of less than `1`. Explanation:

```
T`L`4-0
```

Translate uppercase letters to digits `A=4, B=4, C=2, D=1`, otherwise `0`.

```
\d
0$&$*
```

Convert to unary and prefix a marker `0` to keep count of the number of grades.

```
1
20$*
```

Multiply by `20`.

```
\+
6$*
```

Add 6 for a `+`.

```
1{6}-
```

Subtract 6 for a `-`.

```
O`.
```

Collect the markers and scores together.

```
0+
$.&$*1$.&$*1,$.&$*
```

Add the count to the sum (so that the division will round) and double the count.

```
\D*(1+),(\1)*1*
$#2
```

Divide the sum by the doubled count.

```
.$
.$&
```

Divide by `10`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>165</s> 100 bytes

Thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan) for the whopping 39% size reduction.

```php
function($a){foreach($a as$v)$r+=strpos("FDCBA",$v[$l++*0])+($v[1]?$v[1]..3:0);echo round($r/$l,1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/NToNAFIX3PMUNmaQzzhRLq9FYa20hTdy40R2Shp@hNEEgM7SamD6FCzc@nS9SL0OtTYDM@e65Zw51Xu9vp3VeWySDCeyzTZk066qkJGIfWaVklOR4hkiTLSOKT3Sj6kpTe@F785ktyDYgBedng5BxisINp@brOKObARvLJK9AVZsypUSdk0K4bLzbjy3rLV8XEijReGm2ko2mT8/@wyNj8GEBBCQSJA5xJt/rokol7cHkDnqiUetXXGJsjC6yUlEq9alLoEdvYiyJpYUr@m5nNT3wNxyw2yC7ZVW81E2kGmoc9ySjh8AuXJlkNGG7ZVLIqKQnUThtxToDyjvrBDiJWTfuwc/3Z8@4Cy07ZiP7Em1VmTQyBRLbxzj7pUSx2wezsK13YQULAe1j5MAKfC7A7xvlWsFMwFyAh8iQoXOJrI8QX69/dA6dofGaETc7824yckZdCtJZu/NPPUTeAfNDzNXflcdKrnP9Cw)

#### Original Solution

```php
function($a){$i='array_search';$g=str_split("FDCBA");$r=0;foreach($a AS$v){@$r+=eval("return {$i($v[0], $g)}".($v[1]?$v[1].".3;":";"));}die(round($r/count($a),1));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LCoMwFET3/YoQLiTBRyvdNQ1WW/oDXRaRoPEBouEahVL67VbdHGYYZhjb2OUa28YeoCKKLNXUF64deg5afKFVTCPqTz4ajUXDJNRqdJiPtmsdp8/HPU2okIDqJKsBjS6atUiSF8ziewP0lJl1xykaN2FP1kEO8/uU@QRq8aPh5qIs3hnS8CzphUoqhPyVreE4TH3JAY/FKtz2yI@2TC5Q8TdLmE9YEmxMvZ07ApYJufwB)

This is my first time golfing in PHP, so I probably missed a few places where I could have been more efficient.

#### Original Explanation

PHP is completely and utterly broken, which is why golfing in it is so fun. We approach this problem by using a string and splitting it, using the index as GPA value. The `array_search` function grabs the proper GPA value for us. We then use the `+` or `-` in the input to add or subtract `0.3` to the GPA value and use a standard algorithm to find the average value.

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/PToNAEMbvPMWEbMJuWLC0Go2V1pamiRcvesOm4c9SmiCQXVpNGp/CgxefzhfBYam1yQI7v/nmm486r9u7aZ3XBsnAhzbblUmzrUpKInbIKimiJMc7RIrsGZG2rxpZV4qay0Uwn5mc7MPBitkUv95qqt8Ty7amjju6xTNgY5HkFchqV6aUyIsEL01nzj02/mjHhvGWbwsBlChcn21Eo@jT8@LhkTE4GAAhiTiJV9gT73VRpYJa4E/A4o3cvuIQY2NUkY2MUqHOVRw1ahdjXNzGPe54vVTHwR9yweyMzI5V8Vo1kWyoVtyTjB4Ne3OpnVGE6dZJIaKSnllhtyu2GVC7l/pgk5j1bQt@vj8trS6U6JmJ7It3UUXSiBRIbJ7szJcSi482nK26eJdGuOTQHV0OjHBhc1g4uvKMcMZhziFApMnQvULmIMQncE7KoTvUWt2y9cy874zcUe@CdNbN/NMAUXDE9tHm@m/lKZLn3vwC)

Comment: (You can always remove the `@`s, as outputting junk to STDERR is perfectly fine.)

Comment: One tip I used here was removing `$r=0;` - PHP is really cursed (of course) and lets you add to unassigned variables. Another was using `strpos` instead of `array_search` and `str_split`. (Sorry, but not using `eval` was shorter.)

Comment: I did also change the `die` to `echo` because it would be invalid by our rules, as functions need to be reusable, and not quit the script. (It didnt' cost bytes though.)

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/NToNAFIX3PMUNmaQzzhRLq9FYa20hTdy40R2Shp@hNEEgM7SamD6FCzc@nS9SL0OtTYDM@e65Zw51Xu9vp3VeWySDCeyzTZk066qkJGIfWaVklOR4hkiTLSOKT3Sj6kpTe@F785ktyDYgBedng5BxisINp@brOKObARvLJK9AVZsypUSdk0K4bLzbjy3rLV8XEijReGm2ko2mT8/@wyNj8GEBBCQSJA5xJt/rokol7cHkDnqiUetXXGJsjC6yUlEq9alLoEdvYiyJpYUr@m5nNT3wNxyw2yC7ZVW81E2kGmoc9ySjh8AuXJlkNGG7ZVLIqKQnUThtxToDyjvrBDiJWTfuwc/3Z8@4Cy07ZiP7Em1VmTQyBRLbxzj7pUSx2wezsK13YQULAe1j5MAKfC7A7xvlWsFMwFyAh8iQoXOJrI8QX69/dA6dofGaETc7824yckZdCtJZu/NPPUTeAfNDzNXflcdKrnP9Cw "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang) (v2.0-alpha), 81 bytes

```
O+++=s=n"";W=gP;=n+1n=s++*100&!?70=cA[g-69c*30&]g-44A]g s/=q/+/s n 5=t 10t'.'%q t
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/v2#WyJPKysrPXM9blwiXCI7Vz1nUDs9bisxbj1zKysqMTAwJiE/NzA9Y0FbZy02OWMqMzAmXWctNDRBXWcgcy89cS8rL3MgbiA1PXQgMTB0Jy4nJXEgdCIsIkFcbkEtXG5CK1xuQlxuQi0iXQ==)

The basic algorithm is as follows, with a few golfing optimizations added:

````
# Set `s` and `n` to the empty string. This could be any zero value,3
# but an empty string helps with `OUTPUT`
; + = s = n ""

# Each grade is on a separate line
; WHILE = grade PROMPT
    ; = n + 1 n # increment the amount of grades

    # The grade part is `100 * (c == 'F' ? 0 : 69 - c)`, 
    # ie the grade offset for normal grades, or `0` for `F`.
    ; = grade_part * 100 &(!? 70 = c ASCII [grade) (- 69 c) #nice

    # The modifier is `grade.len == 1 ? 0 : 30 * (44 - grade[1].ascii)`
    ; = modifier_part * 30 (& ]grade (- 44 ASCII ]grade))

    # `s` will be coerced to an int the first tiem around.
    : = sum ++ grade_part modifier_part s

# Calculate the average * 10. To accommodate the rounding rule,
# we add five, then divide (`sum`, which is 100x a GPA) by ten.
; = avg / (+ /sum n 5) 10

# Now, simply output the number in the float format
: OUTPUT ++(+ "" /avg 10) '.' (% avg 10)

```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>168 150</s> 144 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(sum([{'A':4,'A-':3.7,'B+':3.3,'B':3,'B-':2.7,'C+':2.3,'C':2,'C-':1.7,'D+':1.3,'D':1,'D-':0.7,'F':0}[i]for i in n])/len(n)*10+.5)/10
```

Could save some bytes on the dictionary creation.

Returns a float.

Comment: You should use `int(x*10+.5)/10` instead of math.ceil.  It's shorter and fixes a bug (your current solution turn 0.01 into 0.1, which is incorrect).

Comment: you could also save some bytes by packing into a one-line lambda that takes a list as an argument.  you then don't need to print the output or call split on the input, and can skip some variable assignments.  Note also that you can reference a key into a dictionary without it needing a variable (for example: `{"A": 4, "B": 3}["A"]` is valid Python)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υ⁺⌕FDCBA§ι⁰×·³⁻№ι+№ι-﹪%.1f∕ΣυＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7dCoMgGL33KUQYfDKNxi53lUUQLAjaC0S6EkxHadvbO9vNzt3h/I7zsI5uMDG@Z20Uhsa@gu/9qu0ElOIubDMEhjsTNqi1lUDqqhQFYbjwjZXqA5rhnFKGH3pRG@TZleFW22QvXbD@kMmZJP1POaEHbqhLMx5aJ4NxQE7Z5Zl6K71rqaAPC4QUuys7@fThl4ixQAVH4owEEhxFvpsv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated grade strings. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Repeat for each input grade...

```
⊞υ⁺⌕FDCBA§ι⁰×·³⁻№ι+№ι-
```

... calculate its value by looking up the letter in the string `FDCBA` and adjusting by `0.3` depending on the number of `+`s or `-`s.

```
﹪%.1f∕ΣυＬυ
```

Take the average and format it to one decimal place.