# Generate a Tiefling's Traits

Tags: code-golf, random

A Tiefling is a character race, from Dungeons and Dragons, that has this list of possible traits:

- small horns
- fangs or sharp teeth
- a forked tongue
- catlike eyes
- six fingers on each hand
- goat-like legs
- cloven hoofs
- a forked tail
- leathery or scaly skin
- red or dark blue skin
- cast no shadow or reflection
- exude a smell of brimstone.

---

Given a list of Tiefling traits as input, randomly pick 1d4 + 1 (**uniform distribution from 2-5**) traits from that list and output them.

This challenge uses the [standard definition of random](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/9534), and the number and trait selection from the list must *separately* conform to definition 1 from [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/9534):

- All possible [numbers] should be produced with the same probability;
- All possible [traits] should be produced with the same probability;

You are allowed to pick randomly from the list by first shuffling it and taking the top 1d4+1 traits, so long as the shuffle does not favour any item in the list. Repeat selections of the same trait are not allowed.

Here is a non-golfed implementation in Javascript:

```js
const dice = (n, s, a, doSum) => {
  const die = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * s) + 1;
  const dieResults = Array.from(Array(n)).map(each => {
    return die();
  });
  const sum = dieResults.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr + a, 0);
  // logging not required here
  console.log(`rolled '${dieResults.join(` + ${a}, `)} + ${a}${doSum ? ` = ${sum}`:''}'`);
  return doSum ? dieResults.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr + a, 0) : dieResults.map(each => each + a);
};

const shuffleSlice = (num, array) => array
  .map(value => ({
    value,
    sort: Math.random()
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
  .map(({
    value
  }) => value).slice(0, num);

// you can take the list as a string or an actual list
const tieflingTraits = "small horns; fangs or sharp teeth; a forked tongue; catlike eyes; six fingers on each hand; goat-like legs; cloven hoofs; a forked tail; leathery or scaly skin; red or dark blue skin; cast no shadow or reflection; exude a smell of brimstone".split(/;\s+/);

// calling the function
console.log(shuffleSlice(dice(1, 4, 1, true), tieflingTraits))

// outputs like
//  ['goat-like legs', 'cast no shadow or reflection', 'a forked tongue']
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest in bytes wins.

Comment: Some of these are self-contradictory.  Does it have red skin or dark blue skin?  Leathery or scaly?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman take it up with the developers of D&D ... ‍♂️

Comment: That's okay, I was just wondering if you wanted e.g. "red skin" and "dark blue skin" to be separate, mutually-exclusive options, but a bit late to change this now.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman oh, if that were the case they'd be new lines, or I'd have specified you need to split on 'or'. But thanks for checking

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `dice`, 22 bytes

```factor
[ ROLL: 1d4+1 sample ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDRSsQwEHzvVwz3KgoHPp0fIMKhoPgkPuwlmyY0zZZNqlfEb6/p2YLgPs7M7s6MI1NE59eXh8f7A2wwjI41cYRSstJjUC5lGjSkgrum@WpQZ5d7ihFeNOXdL@IotRmiyJ50QGEufqUITrRjiyKpHXlFDZUYOgZPvN3I4QwXUstaLyUwGQ9fbax0K1SuLzuR223HRPngVK2Iy//@UYgrFpmKZ50uDg3FCbkLaSW1aituSTuc4sh/OUO5IMkSy8rnIlN2kU0Jskn4PFoGIfdcSxGHk4Y@17A16nczv@H56Xg8YG9vr/bI1A@R8T6bpcGb@Qc)

A quotation (anonymous function) that takes a list of strings as input and outputs a uniformly random sample of 1d4+1 items of said list.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 22 bytes

```
?O`
,3G`¶
?&0A`¶
?&0A`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU9LTgMxDN37FF6xAgnEASpWLLlC3czLJJrURnYGOhfjAFxsSIuEWFl6fl9HrypP@354O9L98@vx@4sOd48vf3ff4yytcTHXoCw6B5tzFPF37kAvJJzNF0zcTecVlKS3uoCxISjqhXPVGT50ypBUuIhONJv0hxuvYQ5KzT6gI8Zy/HOU2qhBeoFvt9wkbeNYqpKP/0Am8YVPbcUvmiQ6q10LTvZ5JThyQ@rVlHBZJ7BwnDEmWeaT13OM2vgB) Explanation:

```
?O`
```

Uniformly shuffle the input.

```
,3G`¶
```

Keep the first four (0-indexed) newline characters, which also ends up keeping the first five lines.

```
?&0A`¶
```

50% chance to delete the first newline character including the first two lines.

```
?&0A`
```

50% chance to delete the first line.

Comment: Does this output 1-4 or 2-5 from the list? Also trying to figure if your two lots of 50% make this uniform?

Comment: I must have misread how it work then. You're "keeping the first four lines." Then either deleting one (50%) or two (50%) lines. But that never leads to picking 5 traits, only 2, 3 or 4 traits....?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage You're right, and I made that same mistake in my Charcoal answer...

Comment: The calculation is easier to see with the corrected version: there are separate 50% chances of deleting 2 and 1 lines; imagine a two-bit number where each bit has a 50% chance of being 0 or 1 then the number as a whole has a 25% chance of each of 00, 01, 10 and 11; this means that 0-3 lines are uniformly randomly deleted, leaving 2-5 lines.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>7</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ẋṫ4XN¤
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of lists of characters and yields another with 2-5 random entries.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU@7UQQxDM1dhRogow5iCHW2/LnVSozkhdsKmKEOMtJLgAwq2UoW35GQvv87EvO679vn6/bxfnt/9/22b1/nn5eHffcZmaGqiYeMUhzUwCvaI3SiXgNCVpsoQVcpC4WIndtEQCt58HaC3KSQDZ8AYaxQUVIoiv3mqmMqHiLrE8mo0ez/ErFxYMJeydZrb0RewacmwQY/kIQ2wYEX@kMjegfRy8CkzxeBUWaKvakEOi2JAMHncRc0w8Ha7GM2/QI)**

#### How?

```
Ẋṫ4XN¤ - Link: list, A
Ẋ      - get a shuffled copy of A
     ¤ - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  4    -   four
   X   -   random choice from 1-4
    N  -   negate
 ṫ     - tail (the shuffled copy) from (that) 1-indexed index
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 18 bytes

```
*.pick(pick 2..5:)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BTsQwDETv@Yo5sS3SVoAEB1Yr8SVI3tRpQlOnilPYSvvvJV0uXHyYefaMZ87xbZtWPDict8duDnZs9oGXrnt9b7cTlFa45gO32xkxCGvbfaUgzeGEQwuXMj6fnzadKEb4lEWNIxkU1VBPeUZhLt7Qjo7coyQZFjaWSgwjg1dWo@EKF2TgXPcETNbDk/RmSFSOdy7yoMbG9M1SY5LTfxcpRBOZiue83nMtxRU6BjG5@lXpKY@4xIX/VEtaIGkv2KefHcjsItsSkhi@Lj2DoBPXl5LDJYdJa23@BQ)

`pick 2..5:` picks a random number from 2 to 5, then gives that as an argument to the `pick` method on the input list, randomly choosing that many elements from it.

Comment: It would be good to see it working on the input in the question

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Changed.  (I was just trying to keep the TIO link to a minimal length.)

Comment: I like it! I was thrown by having the footer run it 10 times, but it makes sense

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) (Full program), 58 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to @The Fifth Marshal

```python
from random import*;print(sample([*open(0)],randint(2,5)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LTsQwDN3nFF62oxkJISEhOApi4UmdJmpqV3Y6TM_Cphu40xyAe5BOWbCy9N7z-3x-T0uJwuv6NZdwer69BJURFLmrJ42TaDm8Tpq4NIbjlKl5O8hE3Dy078dNtjGPx6e2bXeHP6P19mMj5gxRlM0F5N5AFCyiTlCISnQIQXSgDopwP5PzWHIaCGghc5auEBL3pPWPgdBHiDXP9YLldNdl6s35LBfiGiPB_jliyi4Tlki63HM95gVsSOy08hXpUAc455l21KMVYNkKdvKxCZRCJl-SsKPr3BEg2Eh1kgQ4axqt1qZ97S8)

## [Python](https://www.python.org) (Function), 51 bytes

- -7 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan

```python
lambda a:sample(a,randint(2,5))
from random import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LTsMwEN37FLNrglqEQEiIqiehLKbJOLZij60ZB5qzsKmE4E49APfAaVmwGunN-35857m4xKdPu9t_TcVuns4PAeOhR8BnxZgDNbgW5N5zae7Xj21rrKQIC1SPjzlJufmTbj1n2MFL8Ey3okV8blZ7XrVgk8CCgmdImbi5a19NlsXUNlXVtleL0_lHI4YALgmrsciDQtWqQ8lQiIozuLiN1ENJPExkOizBjwQ0kxr1R7CeB5KqYyDsHLja1QwJy-bCCzSo6UJ6I64xyeo_R_TBBMLiSOZLbodhBh09G6n_ivQoIxzCRFe0Qy3AaSnYp_eFIGQDdcUnNnScegIEjVQnJQsH8VFrbbqu_QU)

Comment: I'm noticing the input has some semicolons and the output sometimes has newline characters?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage the output will always have newline characters, you can use `print(*sample(...` at the cost of one byte to not print them. Not sure if it's nececairy

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1vQR.jpg

Comment: When you iterate over files in python each line will include the trailing newline character (except the last one). That is what you are seeing here

Comment: You can remove the space before the `*` for -1 byte.

Comment: ...avoid all the oddness and save seven by writing a function which accepts a list, [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LTsMwEN37FLNrglqEQEiIqiehLKbJOLZij60ZB5qzsKmE4E49APfAaVmwGunN-35857m4xKdPu9t_TcVuns4PAeOhR8BnxZgDNbgW5N5zae7Xj21rrKQIC1SPjzlJufmTbj1n2MFL8Ey3okV8blZ7XrVgk8CCgmdImbi5a19NlsXUNlXVtleL0_lHI4YALgmrsciDQtWqQ8lQiIozuLiN1ENJPExkOizBjwQ0kxr1R7CeB5KqYyDsHLja1QwJy-bCCzSo6UJ6I64xyeo_R_TBBMLiSOZLbodhBh09G6n_ivQoIxzCRFe0Qy3AaSnYp_eFIGQDdcUnNnScegIEjVQnJQsH8VFrbbqu_QU)

Answer (score 4):

## [Goruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby/9289?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C19.2465#9289), 16 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.s rn 2..5}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pVbdbts2FMZu_RSnThpLri0n2woMQb20HdJtNyvQAruY4RmURNlsKFIgKTe25bzIbnKxXQ7Y8_RpdkhK8k_TosNyEdLnj-fnO-fojz9VGa_uP3T-PoEfpb1DoSgvUwpDWBhT6MvRaM7MooyjROYjK-H_xVzGo5xoQ9VoLnk2q_UiFXcSTrSG1_E7mpgOwPPnTmBB9ALGsNl2kLakKpaaDuD01-s3L1-_vUZOcx2AYBxlUppBTs1CprOcac3EHPIB9MkAzmJkAxhU2jM-gQnyNeVZ5DyYwhSqagw5MckCtWfemA7ycHI-dRZYhkbOzsDbA5jNNBXpbBYY-1AIm6pP1FxXNRsgjmImUjQW0SXhQbdQMtlUzgX3TEoMqeD0Dj07JMK2G0YJ4Tw4vQvtu6d3e0Ydwz0V1tStOynXtCYYuDpyz-YhhEvQZUGVFxdpp_m_l9g62Z0mp8f50CjT6w0gx9N6QmJOG6b3RyFn9PvJRkdGznQ012UcjKJRuOkGUf8q7MITeEPn9LaIqE5IQYPTs3C7HTndPJorWgQqjLRUZoYQSyVUrMkp8yadU1YI1U2pqKUUwdmlZmsawrNnwI4irIPx5ZZCmxYkySfAkQy-ABvJAJw1IoxuYWKAiBQURceEZ8_m1ASmTg5hmsIvJKfXSkk1gG4pmGCGEY7Op609ONkk2-7ApZiq4CI8imSB6aFomsSxoktGDJPiC2pjJXxd3E9ZqllC0KExBFcvoujqtxDGYxTZw3weIYjpbeDVVnkDuouoLIxEssv6plpXaBkLKlyx7QRA9Hu_1qEt0KYyCsPc9YegtwZKwSkOgODgfSeIPthfrZOtnuNC38ba0up8exZ7ALeOg6mxdXKRWNO6aaCPOshPlQcwdJxXn9YWK9aqH2bYgrUIAr5QbElMq4SNuFOvjdcizTuLgNhq_oTljO3lPV4Se3nU8xUoSqOhe7IhW8q5HCBg4q1UPHXAOfQ5CywiLs7PvWZduRyLJiprpveKrdcvy_W605uwsej3v308vHg6YE8uvplWldjurCFKiQZNVu75xn4qZ-8XjPvcnYO7w4pRfpQ7lCuFqTN7Du5-IOdkfR5fKEVW7YuSpzNXtBq6nuoo7yQT-4qvCFbxB3v9pLb1pe2Bbvfjx38WBieUag1QkizAsJxaFSYSt_SuRZlTZbGwr_oWgSbmreYIdMGZ6exeJR4xlhr0ent9HbiQsdvsAEh2WBnCA6THbGJtqRVCnghd4MiGjBNjqGjORzhM8oIgEuvzEaCDMsEZZI9pGNmwNpU16pvSrinouqt19mRjWVu_a-wC4TK5adrforONxvafLrkdoyT6rBpOd04SGpDI1q2hYsN6A7smaurv_-qCuOHgJbGNscNqLYzuJugl_Z5dcTXN4cJrY18_8EJdPyPV3hRxIn6bOAftqKAouLNEj6QbjhsU7rQZ3O5j4uClhyH5n4o_uazTOMXRMrm0Jv5nNW0lP1e4Nqp9_9Gzwg66-mx5Db2J8aA9Vnksmw-23ZfM4Wv2Q8ktfkWTZdUiJ1lG7UeNnbj2u-YhT_f7ORv_VZps-N0_w-_JhkQacEl8HUVPt5784auhm6PZZIJaXZ2jR4C7VejuwBIyIuYYrMKFS1QBhmKCPIdAJtUNbmwjxbyknpgQw9kNBbqitQHNbiHDgUAVmhF-kCzwA8Fz55KYodPgdF5rJFwusYkXUmb6-CnCuCdxSsyCYvdb1zCNK9A3THieQkkkp0TdQMxLusfCNWpASBtNKt9bKUUzjrXCLe0l6K0dbQR0jlsFZAaxYrnGGG2E06nP2v29P_8F)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sample rand 2..5}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBTsQwDEXFllNYs6ZdICGxgYuMZuGmThM1jSs7GaZCnIRNheAM3IXTkE66QKwi_fft_O_3T8ndsn7Yp6-cbPP43TzjK7aK0xwIBGMP92378Fbpz00z56Rgj8dbgINOGAI4lqiHu02wGAcFFlCHMkMiSq4SBMsyUg-J45CpigZT8CMBLbQvUH8B6-NAUtZEIDQOXAlR6cCYmutEoGGfMIHPFEsItvr_K_ShSoEwOZLlGs1gWEBHHyuT4ixyjzJCFzL9QQY1QeStTc8vm0vIBjLJ8-6gS-4JEHSicgm20ImftHTcGp5O9WrrWt9f)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ö¬o2+4ö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9qxvMis09g&input=WyJzbWFsbCBob3JucyIsImZhbmdzIG9yIHNoYXJwIHRlZXRoIiwiYSBmb3JrZWQgdG9uZ3VlIiwiY2F0bGlrZSBleWVzIiwic2l4IGZpbmdlcnMgb24gZWFjaCBoYW5kIiwiZ29hdC1saWtlIGxlZ3MiLCJjbG92ZW4gaG9vZnMiLCJhIGZvcmtlZCB0YWlsIiwibGVhdGhlcnkgb3Igc2NhbHkgc2tpbiIsInJlZCBvciBkYXJrIGJsdWUgc2tpbiIsImNhc3Qgbm8gc2hhZG93IG9yIHJlZmxlY3Rpb24iLCJleHVkZSBhIHNtZWxsIG9mIGJyaW1zdG9uZSJdLVI)

```
ö¬o2+4ö     :Implicit input of array
ö¬          :Random permutation
  o         :Pop & return this many elements
   2+       :  Two plus
     4ö     :  Random integer in range [0,4)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Excel (ms365), 52 bytes

```
=TAKE(SORTBY(A1:A12,RANDARRAY(12)),RANDBETWEEN(2,5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), 20

```bash
shuf -n$[RANDOM%4+2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xTgNBDER7f4ULqFAaxA9EogUkWpTCt@u9XZ3PRvYeyX192ISG9s3YMzNR1Os16lbwoA9fn8f314@3x5en59OgK4lgNdeAQjoHmmNU8m/szL0CYTFfOGM3nTeGRF3awsg7B0S7YGk6s487RaZUsZJmmI364e4TngOS2A/riLES/z5SExCmXtn3e24i2TGWpuBDHySTLzjJxn80UXRUuxXMdr4ZnItw6s0U@LJlRsJYeUyygpO3NUZthl8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⟦⟧θＦ⁺²‽⁴⊞θ‽⁻υθθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@7bsMwDEV3fQVHGXCWolunjh0KGO0YdGBk2hJMU4ko5fH1LpOiRUdd3cdhiFhCRt62S0xM4N/k2OpnLUlm33UwNI2@9ZC6F/eqmmbx@68eTvaccgE/cFP/1MMHyphX/9z9Zk5/2nsS87R7qLPYYNXVW8G26YrMEHMRdRPKrGCVakRHqEQ1OgQbWWiEmmVu5AJWTgsB3UidpitMhknFcgKEIUK0STdnrLuHj2lWFzifSWwmT/qvERM7JqyRyu2xG5BvoEsSV@zflBHLAgdu9KMG1AqS74BjvtwNhSamUFMWR9c2EiDoSnZSnuBQ0qqGTW7bnfkb) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Read in the list of possible traits.

```
≔⟦⟧θ
```

Start with no traits selected.

```
Ｆ⁺²‽⁴
```

Repeat `2-5` times uniformly randomly.

```
⊞θ‽⁻υθ
```

Pick a trait uniformly randomly from the list of traits not already picked.

```
θ
```

Output the final list of picked traits.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 25 bytes

Input comes from the pipeline.

```powershell
random -c(random -mi 2 6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/BbsMwDEN/hbeswHrZYf@jOnJsRLEKyVkboP@e2QY2oDeBfJLIuz7YPLHIOflGIkhqxadPTJHK4lCDJ7I7KnNNXSdEtZVnVC3Lzl0KVCWvDD54rHp@IuaytNPQAqaQkKjM3VuU6nXQwsugg@gPl/ZYo78/oCxdEKaa2I4RJpAc8DWX7lijmjiTrbjJzv9GIK8o2rPP@uiMcRQONevw@bnPDIJvrTo04mZ589aIJ7xOa1l1wzV8/E1bxhe@L@f5Cw)

**Ungolfed:**

```powershell
Get-Random -Count (Get-Random -Minimum 2 -Maximum 6)
```

Straightforward; Get-Random with "-Count x" will randomly select x objects from the pipeline input.

The verb "Get-" can (in dire situations as code golf) be dropped from cmdlet names *<Verb>-<Noun>*; if PS finds no program or cmdlet named "<*noun*>", it will add "Get-" and try to find that. **Disclaimer** Use this for golfing only, never in normal scripts; it'll slow down the script (because it will try to find *<noun>*.exe in the path first every time), and may start unrelated programs on other systems.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>17</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
mÅvαá├mÅ~;3w⌠<
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VU87UgMxDL2Kum2gooSbMBSKLX9mZYuxvEm2oaOjTJkCjsAZ0nOIXGSRM0NBJ72P9F7BnqJw2LZyed//fF@@rqezjW@PD4frx@fTtj1PWpAZkrSq090UsEYFaaAJ2yt0op4MRgjSZvLQpcaFDHHYOc8EtNLwaT5CyDVSM3cFQpcgYfVGRcF@f9MyxaF1LHuq9lKC/ruNmW1nstTU1lsKh7yCzrka0UxjmMc2w44X@sMdaocqI7KXw5A0CkyuZxk0HRdPgKCFrKgE2LVc1IrQ9PIL)

I really hate this language sometimes.. -_- This should in theory have been `áv3w⌠<` (6 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)), but due to a number of bugs, it ended up as 17 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py) instead.

**Explanation:**

*Explanation of the intended solution, and why it didn't work due to bugs:*

```python
á       # Sort the (implicit) input-list by:
 v      #  A random integer in the range [-2147483648,2147483647]
  3w    # Push a random integer in the range [0,3]
    ⌠   # Increase it by 2 (to have the range [2,5] instead)
     <  # Only keep that meany leading items from the shuffled list
        # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

*Bugs:*

1. <s>MathGolf changes all spaces in string inputs to `", "` ([try it online with explicit print](https://tio.run/##VY/NbsNACIRfBfncPlHUA1nP/sh4iWCdxk/vspFy6JFvBpjZedSikq/rcV23xXcWoarWfflaMvfipEZe2R40gFEDM2W1DSsN7eVAkMRD2gbCibnn7UW59QKL7U7gVKlyX0MqyuP77RWU6U2iT/R4qdn/3eYmMQsiIOx8p0gsJ/nWeggWnmAr20Z3OfDhiX1Q1xl51d9pMWRBGk2njNexgph8RxTVTHdru0cRLD9/)). This bug is likely because MathGolf supports multiple inputs both separated by commas and spaces, so when a string or string-list is used that contains spaces, it incorrectly splits them, before interpreting the splitted string as string again..

   This is fixed with the leading `mÆ',-` (only works because the input-strings are all without commas)</s>
   EDIT: Apparently using `'` quotes for strings instead of `"` fixes this issue.
2. MathGolf's sort-by builtin `á` apparently evaluates its body once in some cases, because `áv` and `áf` both result in an unsorted list and act similar as `á1` would.
   This is fixed by replacing it with `mÅvαá├mÅ~;`:

```python
m       # Map over the (implicit) input-list,
 Å      # using 2 characters as inner code-block:
  v     #  Push a random integer from the range [-2147483648,2147483647]
   α    #  Pair the string and random integer together
á       # After the map: sort by:
 ├      #  The left (a third bug, should have been `┤` for right..) item: the random integer
m       # After the sort-by: map again,
 Å      # using 2 characters as inner code-block:
  ~     #  Dump the string and random integer to the stack
   ;    #  And discard the random integer
```

After which we can use the `3w⌠<` explained above to finish the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.rY5ŸΩ£
```

Very straight-forward, but can't find anything shorter. (I initially read the challenge description wrong as 1-4 random outputs, which would be possible in 4 bytes. 2-5 however is a bit longer.)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##VY89TsVADISvYqUGOg6DEIWzmf1RNmtkb@DlPK/iBtRItFwpeJ9EQelvZmyPGM8F5/mgT4/fnz8fX9fzfJ5s41opizab7qbILRmJkmXWV@pAz46ZouiKhbq0tMNJ4F7LCsKBkbNyoVhagnq6EThkytwWl5Jwv795K9LwhipvaH5Sov3bzaX6XME9Q4/bF4HrQbaW5oK6x9nCutJcd/zxwNapyXh5kfdhUcSK0IsMGZd9ATHZBi8qkWYtm3kRTC@/)

**Explanation:**

```python
.r       # Randomly shuffle the (implicit) input-list
  Y5Ÿ    # Push a list in the range [2,5]: [2,3,4,5]
     Ω   # Pop and get a random value from this list
      £  # Only leave that many items from the shuffled list
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Huh, why does 2-5 take *3* more bytes than 1-4?

Comment: @Neil 1-4 could be done with [`4ãΩÙ`](https://tio.run/##VY8xbsQwDAS/QrhOuvwmSEFLK0swLQainJyfkvqqvOP6fMmhDrjiSs7uklw1ngvO8@12/fu9/Zzn@2Qbi1DWVm16mRLXxUgbWeb2SR3o2TFT0rYiUte67HASuEtZQTgwclYulEpd0DxdCRwyZa7RpUW5v969gmV4g@gXqp/UZE@7uYjPAu4Z7bh/EVgOsrVUF5p7nEVuK82y48EDW6eq4@Wo38PSkAShFx0yLnsEMdkGL6qJ5lY28yKYPv4B) (get a random item from the cartesian power of 4, and uniquify it).

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>35</s> 24 bytes

Port of [my Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/252440/11261).

```ruby
~:sample&(-:rand^(2..5))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBBasMwEEXptqcYsigJxFkUCiXQbS4R0jKWR5bqsWQ0UhtvepFuTCF36Fl6msqRF6UrwX9_Rv_P5-X1JdXj9HV4uqSoq8fvj71gPzDdrat9QNc8r-93u4fNpuCfm2pIUeBwPN4CrKRHZjA-OFltZ0GjawV8ADEYBohE0RSCoH3oqIHoXZuoiAoj246ARloWiD2Dtq6lkNc4IFQGTI5RaOsxVtcJpnaZUOzfyOUQXsv_r9BykZgwGgrjNZpCHkE66woL2ZnlBkMHNSf6gxRKBOfnNo1_n12BNJOK1i8OOqeGAEF6ypfwGupge8kd54anU7naNJX3Fw)

Answer (score 0):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), 23 bytes (15 chars)

```
{⍵[(≢⍵)?⍨1+?4]}
```

Explanation:

```
{              } ⍝ defun:
          1+?4   ⍝ roll a d4, add 1
   (≢⍵)?⍨        ⍝ generate random indices
 ⍵[           ]  ⍝ index them into ⍵ to get final traits
```

Comment: 13: `⊢⌷⍨(1+?4)⊂⍤?≢`

Comment: @faunlocke just checked, it doesn't save bytes, it actually adds bytes.

Comment: APL is usually counted in [SBCS bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS) instead of UTF-8, where each character is usually 1 byte, in which case _@faunlocke_'s comment is 2 bytes shorter. [Here an example answer of that.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251899/52210) Also, would you mind adding a link to an online compiler (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#apl-dyalog) or [razetime's APLgolf](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/)) with test code?